# Gostaria de entender como se configura portas (port, ddr, pin) usando o assembler do avr atmega328p

Tags: assembly

Exemplo que estava testando, configurar portas de saída e portas de entrada, para poder executar uma soma, mas não estão funcionando:

```
ldi r21, 0x0a
ldi r22, 0x0b

out PINB, r16
out DDRB, r16
out PORTB, r17

add r21, r22
mov r17, r21
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Um nibble (meio byte) esta sendo carregado em r16. Normalmente o certo é 0x0a ou 0xa0.
2. 0xa0 em DDRB é igual a 0b10100000 o que ativa para saída os pinos 7 e 5. Enquanto 0x0a é igual a 0b00001010 o que ativa para saída os pinos 1 e 3.
3. Para ler uma porta porta o correto é:

   ```
   In  r16, pinb
   ```

Comment: Responder no celular não é bom ...

Comment: Corrigindo a pergunta, pois não compreendi a sua resposta...

Comment: Parte deste exemplo: http://www.avr-tutorials.com/digital/digital-input-output-assembly-programming-atmel-8-bits-avr-microcontrollers